# VBscript RegRead always fails - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: vbscript

The following VBscript code ALWAYS fails to find the specified key in the local registry, even when it's definitely there.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm running 32-bit XP Pro/SP3.

```
Dim winShell
Set winShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If regKeyExists(winShell, "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ProgName\") Then
    wscript.echo "ProgName key found"
Else
    wscript.echo "Key not found!"
End If
Set winShell = Nothing

Function regKeyExists (winObj, key)
    On Error Resume Next
    regKeyExists = True
    Err.Clear
    winObj.RegRead(key)
    If Err <> 0 Then regKeyExists = False
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

The output ALWAYS reads "Key not found!", even when the key is present.  I'm stumped!

Comment: If you remove 'On Error Resume Next' what error are you receiving?  Would the function work if you remove that last trailing "\" from the registry key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain that you're actually looking for a *key*? Usually the `Run` key contains REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ *values* to auto-start programs on login.

Check what happens when you change your code to look for a value `ProgName` by removing the backslash after `ProgName`:

```
If regKeyExists(winShell, "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ProgName") Then
  ...
```

Comment: Previously, I tried it without the trailing slash several times without success, but I tried it again based on your suggestions, @Ansgar Wiechers and @B Hart, and now it works correctly!  Thanks to you both.

The only thing different is that I rebooted before this last attempt, which I fully realize shouldn't make the tiniest difference!  Yet, now it works properly...